# Passing objects from a view to controller

Tags: html, angularjs, object, angularjs-controller

I am passing few parameters from a view to a directive. Currently, I am passing that as

```
<text-logo class="cmp_logo default-logo-style">{ 'logo' => "{{row.logo}}", 'subtext' => "{{row.name}}", 'height' => "75", 'width' => "75", 'cx' => "37", 'cy' => "37", 'r' => "35", 'font_size'=> "25", 'y' => "47", 'x' => "21" }</text-logo>
```

I want to pass the parameters as an object, like

```
'style': {
  'height': 75,
  'width': 75,
  'cx': 37
}
```

How can I implement that in my view? How can I pass it to my controller?

Comment: you probably want to set up a ng-model so you can pass it to controller and back check these examples from docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only need `ng-model="obj"` and you can access it in your controller by $scope. i.e. `$scope.obj`

```
<text-logo ng-model="obj" class="cmp_logo default-logo-style">{ 'logo' => "{{row.logo}}", 'subtext' => "{{row.name}}", 'height' => "75", 'width' => "75", 'cx' => "37", 'cy' => "37", 'r' => "35", 'font_size'=> "25", 'y' => "47", 'x' => "21" }</text-logo>
```

Comment: I would like to have an array of objects, like
```'style': {
  'height': 75,
  'width': 75,
  'cx': 37
}```

Comment: just replace from my previus comment obj with your object called style